# How to get the object created by customElement in a Web Component?

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom

I am building a Web Component to be used in a Framework, which embeds a grid libary.

I have managed to get the grid to display by wrapping it in an HTMLElement Class

```
export default class DataGrid extends HTMLElement {    

    constructor() {
        super(); 

        let tmpl = document.createElement('template');
        tmpl.innerHTML = `
            <div id="lib-datagrid"></div>
        `;

        this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
        this._shadowRoot.appendChild(tmpl.content.cloneNode(true));

        this._rowData = [];

        ...
}
```

and

```
    // Load the grid
    customElements.define('my-grid', DataGrid);
```

I need to be able to pass data into the Grid via a DataGrid instance. However it seems that `createElements.define()` takes a Class rather than an object instance, so I don't have the option to create an Instance (`new DataGrid()`) and pass that in.

My theory is that I should be able to retrieve the created element via the dom tree, but my Web Component lives within a Shadow Dom and my Web Component isn't itself a Dom element (I think) i.e. no "this.getRootNode()" etc, but do have access to `document` and `window`.

[image]

Am I missing something in the `createElement` process or is there a way to find the root node of the current shadow dom?

** Edit - adding Top level WebComponent view

```
export default (state) => {
const { items, alert, loading } = state;
return (
    <div>       
        <div className="card-top">
            <my-grid></my-grid>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

};

** Edit 2

I have found that coding the `class extends HTMLElement` in-line (rather than in a seperate js file) does allow me to update a reference from the objects `connectedCallback()` function.

```
    let myobject = null;
    
    customElements.define('my-grid2', class extends HTMLElement {
        connectedCallback() {
          const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
          shadow.innerHTML = `<p>
            Hello
          </p>`;

          myobject = this;
        }
      });
```

Pending other suggestions - I will work with this and post an answer if it works out.

Comment: your Component becomes a DOM element once appended to the DOM.. that is when the ``connectedCallback`` runs

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman - good to know, however my issue is trying to get a reference to the Element/Object created in the parent WebComponent. The `connectedCallback` runs in the object scope, so has access to `this` but no way to pass it back to the parent WebComponent (from what I see)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman - actually having said that I have found a way (added edit #2 in question) that this might work.

Comment: Another method is to make your Component listen to an Event. Your code X then emits the Event and the Component(s) then report back 'this'. More programming than your global variable solution, but also more save when your Components are used in another page... where someone else could also use your global variable 'myobject'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do this.

By defining the `HTMLElement` class in-line and handling the grid wrapper object in the `connectedCallback()` function, I can get access to references for both the `element` created and the DataGrid wrapper object.

All the DataGrid wrapper requires is the `shadowRoot` created as a constructor parameter.

```
let myElement = null;
let myDataGrid = null;

// Load the grid
customElements.define('my-grid', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {

        let tmpl = document.createElement('template');
        tmpl.innerHTML = `
            <div id="lib-datagrid"></div>
        `;

        const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        shadow.appendChild(tmpl.content.cloneNode(true));

        myDataGrid = new DataGrid(shadow);
        myElement = this;
    }
  });
```

With that I can now, later on, call a function on the `DataGrid` object to update data.

Answer (score 2):

Note that as soon as you have access to an instance of your custom element, you can simply use **constructor theft** to create new instances:

```js
// let's say you have a reference to `<my-grid />` in `el`:
const newEl = new el.constructor;
```

Answer (score 0):

After `customElements.define('my-grid', DataGrid)`, you have to actually create an element using:

```
const elm = document.createElement('my-grid');
const orElm = new DataGrid();

// Use `elm` or `orElm` to pass the data.
```

If your web component is added to DOM tree by some other means, then you must locate it using querySelector or equivalent like:

```
const elm = document.querySelector('my-grid');
```

But if it is nested within some other `shadow-root`, then `querySelector` won't be able to do it. For this purpose, you would have to precisely find the parent element, get its shadow root and then run `querySelector` on that shadow root, something like:

```
const shadowroot = parentElement.shadowRoot;
shadowroot.querySelector('my-grid');
```

On a side note, if you need to query or send the data from outside your web component, then it is probably code smell as you are breaking laws of **encapsulation**. There are other better ways to pass the data to the child component. Or else, you don't need **shadow DOM** API. Just use custom elements without shadow DOM.

Comment: @Harsal - I have added detail on my WebComponent view - which includes the placeholder "my-grid".  On your options seperate comments below (if I am allowed)

Comment: on 1) I think this creates an element, but doesn't add it to a dom and creates a new copy of the object. I can manipulate that object (give it data) but it isn't showing on the screen.  I think I need to get a reference to the object that `customElement.define` creates - annoyingly it doesn't return the reference.

Comment: on 2) - it doesn't find it as (per question) the `my-grid` element it is within a shadow dom.

Comment: on 3) I don't have an `appElement` to start the process in the WebComponent. The only element is created by `customElement.define` and that is not returning the reference.

Comment: @Dazed For the first case, when you create a new child instance, you must somewhere add it in your DOM manually using DOM operations. For second, `customElement.define` doesn't create an instance. You must create it later on. For three, by `appElement` I mean the parent element containing your grid component instance. It refers to that instance.

Comment: the `my-grid` element is already in place - via the WebComponent `view` (as per edit #1 in question) - so I do not have a reference to it.  From my tests `customElement.define` does create an instance (output in log from constructor) and (I believe) replaces my placeholder in the view dom fragment. So no need to create the object later on and no reference. For three - I don't have reference to the parent element - for that I would have to search in the dom fragment (which is same problem as finding `my-grid`)

Comment: @Dazed You are right. But again note that `customElement.define` doesn't create a instance of the element. What is happening here is lazy initialization of your web component. Your grid contains reference to element which is initially not defined. When you define it using `.define` function, the browser starts the lazy initialization of the component.

Comment: ok I understand that now - there is obviously async stuff happening so makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Just to save you typing

You can write this:

```
connectedCallback() {

        let tmpl = document.createElement('template');
        tmpl.innerHTML = `
            <div id="lib-datagrid"></div>
        `;

        const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        shadow.appendChild(tmpl.content.cloneNode(true));

        myDataGrid = new DataGrid(shadow);
        myElement = this;
    }
```

as:

```
connectedCallback() {

        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML = `<div></div>`;

        myDataGrid = new DataGrid(this.shadowRoot);
        myElement = this;
    }
```

Comment: Think you have missed the `const shadow = this.attachShadow(`

Comment: Yup, changed to: ``new DataGrid(this.shadowRoot)`` And the ID on the div isn't required. It is shadowDOM, the div IS your grid

Comment: The key point I think is that in my case the `DataGrid` is a thin wrapper round a library class which needs a reference to an element in the created shadow Dom.  By my reckoning the `DataGrid` is actually the parent of the shadow and the `div` is it's child.  So (with the shadowRoot) I guess the `DataGrid` can find via `getElementsByTagName('div')` [returns an HTMLCollection] OR (of course) by `getElementById('lib-datagrid')` - either way.

Comment: ``...shadowRoot.querySelector("div")``